# Adding X weeks to a date using PHP 5.2

Tags: php, datetime, php-5.2

My shared hosting package at 1and1 only includes PHP 5.2.17 -- so I can't use the `DateTime` object. Very annoying!

I currently have this code

```
$eventDate = new DateTime('2013-03-16'); // START DATE
$finishDate = $eventDate->add(new DateInterval('P'.$profile["Weeks"].'W'));
```

But obviously it won't work.

How can do I the same with code that will work with PHP5.2? (The code adds X number of weeks to a particular date.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just get the timestamp with [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) and add x * seconds of a week

```
$newTime = strtotime('2013-03-16') + ($numberOfWeeks * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7); // 604800 seconds
```

or what I've just found out:

```
$newTime = strtotime('+'.$numberOfWeeks.' weeks', strtotime('2013-03-16'));
```

---

Alternatively you can utilize the `DateTime` class. Use the the method `modify` to change your date (like in `strtotime`):

```
$d = new DateTime('2013-03-16');
$d->modify('+'.$numberOfWeeks.' weeks');
```

Comment: `strtotime()` brings more problems than it seems to be. Use `DateTime` class function to avoid strange bugs when calculating periods and you will never miss even a second.

Comment: @Paul You are aware that it's about the missing `DateInterval` in PHP 5.2? Of course there's always the other answer.

Comment: And what about [`DateTime::modify()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php), which is from _PHP 5.2.0_ ? It also works with positive and negative values. Just few days ago I've corrected bug in my own product bec. I was calculating interval by difference of timestamps and on the margin of 2 (Oct-Nov) months was loosing 2 weeks. Corrected to `DateTime` implementation and that's it.

Comment: @Paul I am aware of the whole set of `DateTime`, thanks. I just didn't came up with that at that specific time. My other answers always indicate to prefer the set of `DateTime`, `DateInterval` and `DatePeriod`. This one was a special case. And also when you have PHP 5.2 then `strtotime` is the least problem you've got!

Comment: Ok, I will _upvote_ after timeout, but I think it is better to improve this answer with one more solution.

Comment: Hey, :) update your answer with `DateTime` and will _upvote_, I remember! There is 10 points left for you to have almost round rep :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the DateTime object in PHP 5.2, it's just the *add* method that was added in PHP 5.3. You can use [the modify method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) in PHP 5.2.

```
$finishDate = $eventDate->modify('+'.$profile["Weeks"].' weeks');
```

Please note that this will modify the object on which you perform the operation. So $eventDate will be altered too.